# Laravel Form button inside foreach not submitting

Tags: html, forms, laravel

i tried putting my form inside the foreach so that the value passed in the form is the right value for the result not the last value. but the button inside the form is not submitting (nothing happens after clicking the button).

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Receiver's Name</th>
              <th>Receiver's Contact</th>
              <th>Package Type</th>
              <th>Date Requested</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody class="list">

            @foreach($result as $res)
            <form role="form" method="POST" action="/search ">
            <input type="hidden" name="requestID" value="{{ $res->id }}">
            <tr>
              <td class="name"> {{ $res->receiverLname }},
                   {{ $res->receiverFname }}</td>
              <td class="contact"> {{ $res->receiverContact }} </td>
              <td class="type"> {{ $res->packType }} </td>
              <td class="date"> {{ $res->updated_at }} </td>
              <td><button class="btn"> View Transaction </button></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
            @endforeach

          </tbody>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind guys. i just tried putting the value in the button instead in the input hidden type and im getting the right value in the post. :D

i get rid of the input type="hidden"

and make my button this way

```
 <button class="btn" name="requestID" value="{{ $res->id }}">
```